Supabase - filtering in nested columns?
TL;DR: how do i filter nested arrays in supabase from javascript dynamic querying?
my project is in next.js and i decided to try using supabase (never used anything else, very beginner!!)
so in supabase i have:

table blog with columns id, title, date, obs_date, content, weather
table seen_objects with columns id, name, other_names, wiki
table that joins many-to-many blog and seen_objects, called blog_seen_objects with columns blog_id (connected to blog.id) and seen_object_id (connected to seen_objects.id)

the whole idea i am working on right now is a filter for a blog search bar. here is how i fetch the posts:
//fetch posts from supabase
const fetchPosts = async () => {
  setLoading(true);

  //query start
  let query = supabase.from("blog").select(`
    id,
    title,
    date,
    obs_date,
    content,
    seen:seen_objects!inner ( id, name, other_names, wiki ),
    weather
  `);

  //search string filter
  if (baseQuery.search) {
    query = query.or(
      `title.ilike.%${baseQuery.search}%,content.ilike.%${baseQuery.search}%`
    );
  }

  //date filter
  if (baseQuery.filters.date?.start && baseQuery.filters.date?.end) {
    query = query
      .gte("date", baseQuery.filters.date.start)
      .lte("date", baseQuery.filters.date.end);
  }

  //observation date filter
  if (baseQuery.filters.obs_date?.start && baseQuery.filters.obs_date?.end) {
    query = query
      .gte("obs_date", baseQuery.filters.obs_date.start)
      .lte("obs_date", baseQuery.filters.obs_date.end);
  }

  //stuck HERE :(
  if (baseQuery.filters.seen && baseQuery.filters.seen.length > 0) {
    const seenIds = baseQuery.filters.seen.map((obj) => obj.id);
    console.log(seenIds);
    seenIds.forEach((id) => {
      query = query.in("seen_objects.id", [id]);
    });
  }

  const { data, error } = await query;
  if (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching posts:", error);
  } else {
    setBlogPosts(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  setLoading(false);
};

and here is an example of data:
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "The Future of Space Travel",
    ...
    "seen": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Sirius",
        "wiki": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius",
        "other_names": ["Alpha Canis Majoris", "Dog Star"]
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Andromeda Galaxy",
        "wiki": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy",
        "other_names": ["M31", "NGC 224"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Exploring Mars: The Next Frontier",
    ...
    "seen": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Sirius",
        "wiki": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius",
        "other_names": ["Alpha Canis Majoris", "Dog Star"]
      }
    ]
  }
]

the part where i commented "stuck HERE" is the one i have problems with. i have an array of seenIds, which contains those ids, that should be in the post that gets selected. so basically, the code should select those posts, that in "seen" contain arrays with matching ids to the ids in seenIds
based on the example data, if seenIds = [1,4] or [4,1] then i should only see the first post. if seenIds = [4] then i should see both posts
the current code i have works, but only for one value in seenIds; if there's more it doesn't work anymore. how do i get it to work no matter how many values i have in seenIds?
any help is appreciated! sorry if this is messy, i have been struggling with this for a couple of days i am on the verge of giving up!
